# Script not able to execute because of net location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I can not execute this script:

```
@ECHO off
for /R %%G in (*INF*.txt) do (
    pushd "%%~dpG"
    FOR %%H IN (*RES*.txt) DO (
        copy "%%~G" + "%%~H" "%date% %time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.csv"
        ren "%%~G" "%%~nxG.ok"
        ren "%%~H" "%%~nxH.ok"
    )
    popd
)
```

I have the following Message:

> "\W12DC-FILE\MA-Daten\CMMWS\CAQ-Import-Rauheit-Kontur-Rondcom\Konturograph"
>   CMD.EXE wurde mit dem oben angegebenen Pfad als aktuellem Verzeichnis gestartet.
>   UNC-Pfade werden nicht unterstützt.
>   Stattdessen wird das Windows-Verzeichnis als aktuelles Verzeichnis gesetzt.

That means:

> CMD.exe was started with following Path. UNC-Pahts are not supported. Instead of that was the Windows Directory as actual Directory set.

If i execute the script locally it works fine.

How can I let it work?

Comment: How are you executing the script? It seems like you are trying to call `cmd.exe` from the UNC path... possibly from the content result of `INF.txt` Show samples of `INF.txt` and `RES.txt` content please.

Comment: I would suggest you change both instances of `%%~G`, to `%%~nxG`, as you're already inside the directory, so don't need to use the full path!

Comment: What is confusing you about the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Like Squashman said, you can start a batch file from an UNC path, but cmd.exe can't handle them, therefore the windows directory will be used as current path.

It's possible to access the original starting UNC-path by `%~dp0`.

You could use `pushd` to create temporary drive letters for them, but `%%~dpG` doesn't work, because for your sample path from `"*INF*.txt"` you get
`C:\W12DC-FILE\MA-Daten\CMMWS\CAQ-Import-Rauheit-Kontur-Rondcom\Konturograph`

But it's even easier when you replace `COPY` with `XCOPY` as it can handle also UNC-pathes

```
...
XCOPY "%%~dp0\%%~G"  ...
ren "%%~dp0\%%~G" "%%~dp0\%%~G.ok"
```